# Sampling on vertical axis in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am new to `tikz/pgfplots`. I just wanted to make two figures side by side showing Riemann and Lebesgue sampling. Riemann sampling here implies that sampling is uniform on horizontal axis and non-uniform on vertical axis. Lebesgue sampling is its vice versa. I have made Riemann sampling so far but I am facing difficulties drawing Lebesgue sampling.

Here is the plot I made for Riemann sampling. Can anyone suggest how I could plot Lebesgue sampling?

[image: Riemann sampling]

The code for this plot is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,
declare function={
f(\x)=2+sin(deg(\x-2))+sin(deg(3*\x))/2+sin(deg(5*\x))/8 + 
sin(deg(7*\x))/28;
}
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xtick ={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4},
ytick ={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4},
xticklabels = {$x_0$,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$, $\ldots$, $x_{n-1}$,$x_n$},
yticklabels = {$y_0$,$y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$, $\ldots$, $y_{n-1}$,$y_n=b$},
ymin = -0.2,
ymax = 3.7,
xmin = -0.2,
xmax = 5.2,
x=3cm,y=2cm,
axis line style = thick,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]

\addplot [  
domain=1:4,
samples=300,
line width=1pt,
fill=none, draw=none,
fill opacity=0.1
] {f(x)} \closedcycle;

\addplot [
domain=0:5,
samples=300,
line width = 1pt, red] {f(x)};

\addplot [
ycomb, thick, blue,
no markers,
samples at={1,1.5,...,4}
] {f(x)};

\addplot [
xcomb, thick, blue,
no markers,
samples at={1,1.5,...,4}
] {f(x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

We can see that intervals on `y-axis` are non-uniform and those on `x-axis` are uniform. I need something opposite to that (equispaced samples on vertical axis, making the `x-axis` intervals non-uniform).

[image: Fig (a) is Riemann sampling and fig (b) is Lebesgue sampling]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please describe in some more detail what you want? Do you want horizontal lines at $y_0$, $y_1$ etc. and wonder how you can compute the intersections with `f(x)`?

Comment: I want something like the example figure I just added in the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perhaps use the `intersections` library:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,
declare function={
f(\x)=2+sin(deg(\x-2))+sin(deg(3*\x))/2+sin(deg(5*\x))/8 + 
sin(deg(7*\x))/28;
}
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xtick ={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4},
ytick ={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4},
xticklabels = {$x_0$,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$, $\ldots$, $x_{n-1}$,$x_n$},
yticklabels = {$y_0$,$y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$, $\ldots$, $y_{n-1}$,$y_n=b$},
ymin = -0.2,
ymax = 3.7,
xmin = -0.2,
xmax = 5.2,
x=3cm,y=2cm,
axis line style = thick,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]


\addplot [
name path=plot, % <-- added
domain=0:5,
samples=100,
line width = 1pt, red] {f(x)};

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,1.5,...,4}{%
 % draw (invisible) horizontal path at the y-value given by 1,1.5,...,4
 \path[name path=a] (axis cs:0,#1) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#1);

 \draw[thick,blue,
   % find intersections of the plot and the horizontal path
   name intersections={of=plot and a, total=\t,name=i}]
   % only draw line if an intersection was found
   \ifnum \t > 0
   (axis cs:0,#1) -| (i-1 |- {axis cs:0,0})
   plot[mark=*] coordinates {(i-1)}
   \fi 
;
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is just one thing. I do not need extra intersections. I mean when the horizontal line first intersects $f(x)$, it should terminate. At the point of termination, there should be a vertical line.
e.g. In the solution, the horizontal line from $y_1$ intersects $f(x)$ at three points. However, only first intersection is required. Further extension of the horizontal line and the extra vertical lines due to further intersections are not needed.

Comment: @AbhinavSinha Then the code can be made a bit simpler, see update.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Works for me. One final thing..how can I add markers at each intersection?

Comment: @AbhinavSinha See [update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/414471/revisions).