# automating xbar as ybar in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am endeavoring to make a demonstration of the conceptual difference between the Lebesgue V Riemann integrals.  It's easy to automate the ybar command to give left right or midpoint sums as seen at [Placing coloured rectangles on a plot, using points from the plot - Riemann Sums](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140207/placing-coloured-rectangles-on-a-plot-using-points-from-the-plot-riemann-sums).

I could make the boxes by hand a couple of different ways, but I would like to avoid brute force if possible. The main trouble is that xbar always wants to go back to xmin (which again is an obvious means of one-at-a-timing it) Any ideas on how to automate the xbar command as with the ybar above to make sideways "Lebesgue Sums"?

Comment: alternatively, is there a method of say, stacking "squished" ybars?

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us how precisely the diagram should look like, and even better if you could show us what you have tried.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414450/194703) answer your question? If not, can you please explain your question a bit more?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#/media/File:RandLintegrals.png                               i am trying to generate the bottom image, but without having to code each individual rectangle

Answer (score 2):

Like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414450/194703), you can use intersections here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick,name path=A] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0.8) (2,1) (3.5,0.6) (4,0)};
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \foreach \X [count=\Z] in {0,0.5,...,4}
   {\path[name path global=v-\Z,overlay] (\X,0) --  (\X,0|-current bounding box.north);
   \draw[name intersections={of=A and v-\Z,by=i-\Z},blue,fill=blue!20] 
   \ifnum\Z>1
    let \p1=(i-\the\numexpr\Z-1),\p2=(i-\Z) in
    (\X-0.5,0) rectangle (\X,{max(\y1,\y2)})
    \fi;
   \draw[name intersections={of=A and v-\Z,by=i-\Z},blue,fill=blue!80] 
   \ifnum\Z>1
    let \p1=(i-\the\numexpr\Z-1),\p2=(i-\Z) in
    (\X-0.5,0) rectangle (\X,{min(\y1,\y2)})
    \fi;}
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
  \draw[thick,name path=B] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0.8) (2,1) (3.5,0.6) (4,0)};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \foreach \Y [count=\Z] in {0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}
    {\path[name path global=h-\Z,overlay] (0,\Y) --  (4,\Y);
    \draw[name intersections={of=B and h-\Z,by={i-\Z-1,i-\Z-2}},red,fill=red!20] 
     \ifnum\Z>1
      let \p1=(i-\the\numexpr\Z-1\relax-1),\p2=(i-\the\numexpr\Z-1\relax-2),
       \p3=(i-\Z-1),\p4=(i-\Z-2)
       in
    ({min(\x1,\x3)},\Y-0.2) rectangle ({max(\x2,\x4)},\Y)
    \fi;
    \draw[name intersections={of=B and h-\Z,by={i-\Z-1,i-\Z-2}},red,fill=red!60] 
     \ifnum\Z>1
      let \p1=(i-\the\numexpr\Z-1\relax-1),\p2=(i-\the\numexpr\Z-1\relax-2),
       \p3=(i-\Z-1),\p4=(i-\Z-2)
       in
    ({max(\x1,\x3)},\Y-0.2) rectangle ({min(\x2,\x4)},\Y)
    \fi;
    }
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]