# Lebesgue Integral on Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I recently discovered tikz packages, I'm completely new to this. I started to read the manual and manage to do some very simple things, but I still have a lot of difficulty with the language.

I'm writing myself some notes on the Lebesgue Integral, and I'd like to put the figures below, but I have no idea how to plot them.[image]

Comment: Try to do something. You can play with [matcha](https://www.mathcha.io/).

Comment: It would be nice to see answers for that question

Comment: We need a M(not)WE to start...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414450/47927 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532084/47927

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to do this with tikz, but since you got no answers so far, I give you a start on how you can do something similar in MetaFun. This might give you an idea on how to proceed with tikz. The path `fun` is your function, `N` is the number of colors.

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
numeric u ; u := 1cm ;
path fun ; fun := ((0.2,-0.2){right} .. 
                   (3.5,5.5){right} .. 
                   (6,2.3){right} .. 
                   (9,3.1){right} .. 
          {dir -30}(12,-0.25)) ;
numeric miny ; miny := 0 ;
numeric maxy ; maxy := ypart urcorner boundingbox fun ;
numeric N ; N := 8 ;
numeric level[] ;
rgbcolor levelcolor[] ;
path ip[] ;
path tmppath ;

for i = 1 upto N :
    level[i] := miny + (maxy - miny)*i/N ;
    message(level[i]) ;
    % levelcolor[i] := (i/N)[red,yellow] ;
    levelcolor[i] := ( uniformdeviate(1), uniformdeviate(1), uniformdeviate(1) ) ;
    ip[i] := fun firstintersectionpath ((-infinity,level[i]) -- (infinity,level[i])) ;
endfor

for i = 1 upto N :
    for j = 0 step 2 until (length(ip[i]) - 1) :
        tmppath := ( (point j of ip[i]) -- 
                     (point (j + 1) of ip[i]) -- 
                     (xpart point (j + 1) of ip[i], 0) -- 
                     (xpart point j of ip[i], 0) -- 
                     cycle ) ;
        % unfill tmppath ; % no gain
        fill tmppath scaled u withcolor levelcolor[i] ;
    endfor
    if i < N :
        draw ((0,level[i]) -- (0, level[i+1])) scaled u withpen pencircle scaled 2 withlinecap butt withcolor levelcolor[i] ;
    fi
endfor ;

draw fun scaled u ;
drawdoublearrow ( (0,6) -- origin -- (13,0) ) scaled u ;
\stopMPpage
```

Save the file as `lebesgue.tex` and run with `context lebesgue.tex` to get `lebesgue.pdf`. With `N = 8` we get

[image: lebesgue integral]

The colors are random. With `N = 25` we instead get

[image: more accurate lebesgue integral]

Finally, by altering the definitions of `levelcolor[i]`, we end up with

[image: same but with different colors]

Comment: A very minor point.  But `boundingbox` is redundant in this `numeric maxy ; maxy := ypart urcorner boundingbox fun;`.  You can just write `maxy = ypart urcorner fun;`

Comment: True, thanks! (There are probably more possible improvements, this was merely a first try.)